# Load script only on selected Pages

Tags: functions

The following function within my functions.php loads a JS script..

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myashdrop',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dropdown.jquery.min.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

How could i modify this function so that the JS script is loaded only on specified pages (perhaps by providing their ID in the function's arguments..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional tag such as [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page). Register your script on hook `wp_enqueue_scripts` and enqueue it in if statement :

```
   wp_register_script('myashdrop',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dropdown.jquery.min.js',
    array('jquery'));

if (is_page(PAGEID)) { wp_enqueue_script('myashdrop'); }
```

Comment: thanks but i am also using multiple pages and looking for optimum syntax.. can i separate PAGEID by commas ?

Comment: sure, in array: `is_page(array(ID1,iD2))`

Comment: last question ! how can i enqueue multiple scripts at the same time using the is_page(PAGEID) syntax .. ?

Comment: You can use multiple `register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: ok so i can't use array in there... ? i need to repeat wp_enqueue

Comment: I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, when using if is_page(1) { wp_enqueue_script('myashdrop');}

Comment: I've edited code, I forgot the brackets after `if`